# Code-First equivalent in Ruby

Tags: .net, ruby, entity-framework, code-first, rails-activerecord

I'm suuuuper lazy and don't like making migrations. I want to make models I'm going to use anyway and have something else figure out the migrations for me in ruby because .Net has spoiled me. Is there a gem that will give me active record migrations from models? Can that even be possible since you never explicitly set types in ruby?

Comment: This is not The Rails Way. If you go agains rails, you will suffer miserably. You've been warned. :)

Comment: Not going to happen - column type detection being the primary problem as you mention.  Think of the migration as the only place you need to specify a model's attribute 'type', and you'll see you're not missing much...

Comment: Meh, I mix and match stuff for silly personally projects. I'm using active-record with sinatra right now... I'm not scared! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) instead of ActiveRecord.

Sample Code from the DataMapper Documentation:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'

DataMapper::Logger.new($stdout, :debug)
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'mysql://localhost/test')

class Person
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,   Serial
  property :name, String, :required => true
end

DataMapper.auto_migrate!
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you! Side question, will DataMapper.auto_upgrade! work from the git-go or do I need to DataMapper.auto_migrate! first?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make any sense. Your models pull data their structure from the schema, they don't contain column/table definitions. There is no way to "push" table structure from your models into migrations, it's impossible. The data just isn't there.

This model, as written, may have persist to a table with a thousand columns or one column, there is no way of knowing:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Just use the Rails generators to produce your models and migrations at the same time.

Comment: In theory, they could be extracted from attr_accessible and associations via rake task - although this won't always be accurate.  Then again Code First migrations aren't always accurate either...

Comment: Not even close to enough information is encoded in attr_accessible, associations and validations. You can't do it.

Comment: Agreed - because of missing type info, as I commented above.

Comment: No, **not** because of missing type info. Because of missing **everything**. As I said, my `User` model above may have a "first_name" field. You *don't know*, because I haven't referenced it in any way.

Comment: You would likely have an attr_accessible entry for `first_name`

Comment: I'm talking about making the model first and letting the database be generated from it. As @PinnyM said multiple times, it would be difficult because you don't know the type.

Comment: @Justin, the point here is whether you can even detect the columns that are needed.  ActiveRecord doesn't require any mention of them in the model.  I only pointed out that there is _usually_ some reference to them (indirect in some cases), although not guaranteed.  This whole point is moot because of the types anyhow.

Comment: @PinnyM Maybe. Maybe not. Most fields in most models in a non-trivial app *shouldn't* be whitelisted via `attr_accessible`, as users shouldn't be slamming data into most of your models. It doesn't matter. Even *one column*, anywhere in your app, which doesn't have an `attr_accessible` suddenly breaks the *entire concept*. It can't work.

Comment: @PinnyM I don't even care if I use active-record specifically, I'm just looking for an Entity Framework Code First equivalent in Ruby. Maybe I shouldn't have tagged this with ruby-active-record =\

Comment: @Justin **NO**. The type doesn't matter, this isn't about the type, stop talking about **type**. Your model may be persisting to a document store which doesn't even believe in data types! The problem is that whole columns will have **no reference what so ever in the model**. My example above is really clear here. My `User` model, *as written*, is a completely valid model, and there is no way of gleaning *any* information about its columns based on the model definition.

Comment: @Justin, maybe not :)  DataMapper sounds more like what you are looking for, although it doesn't support code first out of the box either.  Could be done more easily though...

Comment: @meager I don't think we're on the same page. I'm talking about creating db tables from ruby models. I'm saying I wouldn't be able to tell what type the database column should be.

Comment: @Justin So am I! AHHHH. It's not about *data type*! Data type is not preventing you from doing this! You can just make everything a `varchar(255)` and have it work just fine, or look at validations and figure out which things *might* be better stored as integers. The problem is that you **cannot know what to even name your columns, or if there even are columns**. You need to actually know what the columns are before you can worry about their type!

Comment: @meagar: I don't think Justin is going to get it very fast - coming from EF and all :)  Justin, consider how EF extracts columns from the model attributes.  Now pretend those attributes are not written anywhere.  How would EF detect the columns to use for the migration? Well, in ActiveRecord, the attributes _don't have to be written anywhere_.

Comment: @pinnym At least let me get some ice for these burns. Geez. =) I could come up with some convention for what should and shouldn't be columns, who cares?

Comment: @Justin - it's not your fault. I would blame EF for this... ;)  Then again, ActiveRecord is pretty unique this way.

Answer (score 1):

> since you never explicitly set types in ruby

Moreover, you never even **list the fields** in models. ActiveRecord discovers them from DB schema, which *the* repository of schema knowledge. It just works this way. Trying to make it work the other way will inflict great pain and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a legacy database you don't need migrations, nor do you want them. Your DBA would probably kill you if you tried to use one.

That said, I've reversed-engineered legacy databases using Sequel, to create my models for tools we use in-house, that didn't give us the database layouts.

As part of that I was accessing the schema via Sequel, and grabbing field names and data types and sizes. That is the information you need to rebuild migrations.

It's not a magic bullet. You'll have to stop being "super lazy" and "silly" and write code to do this, but it's all doable.

Dump the schemas by hand, and write code to pick out the important information, and write that into a single migration file to jump start your system.